# Httpd restrict access to selected AD's group

Tags: apache, active-directory, httpd.conf

I have 2 Active Directory groups, group1 and group2 and I have configured the httpd.conf to allow group1 to access the URL:8443. But when I access the URL:8443 with user from group2, it prompts the BASIC authentication. How can I disable the prompt of the BASIC authentication?

```
    <VirtualHost *:8443>
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        AuthName "Test"
        AuthType SSPI
        SSPIAuth On
        SSPIAuthoritative On
        SSPIDomain TESTDOMAIN
        <RequireAll>
            <RequireAny>
                require sspi-group TESTDOMAIN\group1                    
            </RequireAny>
            <RequireNone>
                Require user "ANONYMOUS LOGON"
            </RequireNone>
        </RequireAll>
    </VirtualHost>
```

I looked at the httpd's error log file and could see that whenever I login to user from group2, it will print

```
[authnz_sspi:error]access to /url/app.html failed, reason TESTDOMAIN\user2 does not meet requirements for user to be allowed access
[authz_core:error] user TESTDOMAIN\user2 authorization failure for /url/app.html
```

Could it be that authz_core prompts the basic auth? how can I disable the prompt of the basic auth?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by putting the **AuthzSendForbiddenOnFailure On** in the httpd.conf. Hope it will be useful to anyone facing the same issue as me.